# "Престарелая бабушка"

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Допустимо ли такое выражение? Разве не являются его обе части слишком синонимичными, из-за чего возникает тавтология?

Comment: А с чего бы они стали синонимичными? Полно сорокалетних бабушек, или для вас это тоже престарелые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от контекста. Если речь о бабушке, как о матери одного из родителей, то синонима нет. Такая бабушка может быть и престарелой, и молодой.

Второе значение слова указывает на солидный возраст женщины, вполне возможно, незнакомой.

Поэтому выражение "Я видел на автостанции какую-то престарелую бабушку" содержит избыточность, а вот написать "Машина бабушка престарелая, не то что у Серёжи, у него молодая" вполне допустимо.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что в контексте незнакомой женщины наблюдается _противоречие_ между дипломатично-доброжелательным, тёплым наименованием "бабушка" и формальным, безжалостным эпитетом, означающим " практически отжившая своё". По этой причине в сочетании с "бабушкой" естественнее что-нибудь вроде "совсем старенькая".